# How do I change Xcode Valid Architectures via the command line tool?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I have a cordova project, that is not compatible with the ARM 64 iOS processor. I know how to change the valid arch's in Xcode, but I'm trying to get a continuous integration server setup, and I need to be able to set the valid arch's via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the environment variable `ARCHS` to `xcodebuild` (assuming that's how you're building).  It should be at the end of your command.  Something like:

`xcodebuild -scheme <myscheme> -workspace <myworkspace> ARCHS=\$\(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT\)`

(Figured out the escaping and updated.  You might be able to find an escaping format that looks better.)